# App crashes instantly after opening google sign in screen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, backend, mern

The app crashes whenever I go to Google Sign in screen. I don't even have to click anything, it just crashes.

> Error: The verifyIdToken method requires an ID Token at OAuth2Client.verifyIdTokenAsync (/app/node_modules/google-auth-

Google Login Implementation:

```js
exports.googleController = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { idToken } = req.body;

    client
      .verifyIdToken({ idToken, audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("GOOGLE LOGIN RESPONSE", response);
        const { email_verified, name, email } = response.payload;
        if (email_verified) {
          User.findOne({ email }).exec((err, user) => {
            if (user) {
              const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SEC, {
                expiresIn: "7d",
              });
              const { _id, email, name, isAdmin } = user;
              return res.json({
                token,
                user: { _id, email, name, isAdmin },
              });
            } else {
              let password = email + process.env.JWT_SEC;
              user = new User({ name, email, password });
              user.save((err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.log("ERROR GOOGLE LOGIN ON USER SAVE", err);
                  return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "User signup failed with google",
                  });
                }
                const token = jwt.sign({ _id: data._id }, process.env.JWT_SEC, {
                  expiresIn: "7d",
                });
                const { _id, email, name, isAdmin } = data;
                return res.json({
                  token,
                  user: { _id, email, name, isAdmin },
                });
              });
            }
          });
        } else {
          return res.status(400).json({
            error: "Google login failed. Try again",
          });
        }
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Google Cloud has three token types: OAuth access and refresh tokens; OIDC identity tokens. Your code is failing to validate the token because it expects an OIDC Identity Token. What are you passing the function?

Comment: Agreeing with John Hanley, how are you passing the `idToken` to the function? The documentation shows an [example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library) of the argument to `verifyIdToken()`, which you can try to use just in case. Also, it would be useful to include the full error trace, since it looks incomplete. Are you implementing the backend server sign-in, or a different type of Google sign-in? Also, is this code running in a Cloud Function or in a different environment?